# Failed lookup for key [user] in <User: test> exception when unit testing

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I have an app that can `send/cancel/accept/delete` friend requests and I am trying to test it, however when I'm accepting a friend request and adding users to each others friends lists I am getting a `Failed lookup for key [user] in <User: test>` exception.

In my test I create a friend request object and send an accept `get` request to the view which should add each one of the users to each one of their friends lists and delete the `friend_request`.

Debugging shows that the error happens after this line in the view: `user1.friends.add(user2)`, so essentially `user2` is being added to `user1` friends list but adding `user1` to `user2` friends list throws the exception that was mentioned above.

**models.py**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    name = models.CharField('Full Name', max_length=35, unique=True, 
                                                        null=False, 
                                                        blank=False)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField("User", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class FriendRequest(models.Model)
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='to_user',
                                      on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='from_user',
                                        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.db import transaction

def accept_friend_request(request, pk):
    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            from_user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
            f_request = FriendRequest.objects.filter(
                from_user=from_user,
                to_user=request.user
            ).first()
            user1 = f_request.to_user
            user2 = from_user
            
            user1.friends.add(user2)
            print(user1.friends.all())
            
            user2.friends.add(user1)
            print(user2.friends.all())
            
            f_request.delete()
            return redirect(request.get_full_path())

    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
    return HttpResponse('User does not exist')
```

Here I am using the `transaction.atomic()` to prevent the exception from breaking the unittest transaction.

**tests.py**

```
def setUp(self):
    self.client = Client()
    self.user = User.objects.create_user(email='test@gmail.com', 
                                         name='test', 
                                         password='test')
    self.user1 = User.objects.create_user(email='test1@gmail.com', 
                                          name='test1', 
                                          password='test1')
    self.client.force_login(self.user)

def test_accept_friend_request(self):
    friend_request = FriendRequest.objects.create(from_user=self.user1, 
                                                  to_user=self.user)
    self.client.get(reverse('accept_friend_request', 
                             kwargs={'pk': self.user1.pk}), follow=True)
    self.assertIn(self.user, self.user1.friends.all())
    self.assertIn(self.user1, self.user.friends.all())
```

Here is the result of running the test: (You can also see the result of the first print statement and the exception being printed)

```
Ran 1 test in 1.266s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
<QuerySet [<User: test1>]>
Failed lookup for key [user] in <User: test>
```

**UPDATE**

changing Exception to IntegrityError resulted in the following error:

```
raise VariableLookupError(django_elasticsearch_dsl.exceptions.VariableLookupError:
Failed lookup for key [user] in <User: test>
```

looks like elasticsearch-dsl has something to do with the exception here.

**UPDATE**

When debugging exception message changes to

```
Failed lookup for key [name] in <FriendRequest: FriendRequest object (1)>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally managed to make it run correctly by changing the redirect to `request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/')`, looks like it had problems with redirect looping.